# how to test whether hdfs file exists using Bash

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I want to write a Bash script to check whether (or not) a file exists in a certain location.  I have a couple of variables I am using and so far have this working:

```
if hdfs dfs -test -e $NIFI/cust_accounts/$CURRPART; then echo $NIFI/cust_accounts/$CURRPART partition is current on HDFS; fi
```

However, I really want to be able to return an "else" statement.  Meaning
"if file exists then 123 else (if does not exist) 999".

Can someone help me construct an "else" statement?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `[` is (effectively) just another command. So where you may be used to `if [ ... ]; then ... ; else ... ; fi`, what you have isn't really any different. You replace the `[ ... ]` part with your call to `hdfs`, and you end up with the same syntax:

```
if hdfs dfs -test -e $NIFI/cust_accounts/$CURRPART
then
  echo $NIFI/cust_accounts/$CURRPART partition is current on HDFS
else
  echo $NIFI/cust_accounts/$CURRPART partition is NOT current on HDFS
fi
```